# Getting many values in an array in perl

Tags: perl

I am writing a prel program in which I have an input file containing a pattern as:

```
FIELDS=(1,2,3,4)
```

OR

```
FIELDS=(1,10,3,A,11,10,7,D,9,10,11,A)
```

Number of values are not constant but in the bunch of 4. There could be 4,8,12, or 16 or more values.

I want to save these field values in seperate variables. 
For which I am setting values as

```
if($filed1=~m/^\"SORT FIELDS"\s*=\s*"("\s*(.*?)[,]+(.*?)[,]+(.*?)[,]+(.*?)[,]+[,]*")"/sgim)
.
.

$val1 = $1;
$val2 = $2;
$val3 = $3;
$val4 = $4;
```

But this will not serve my purpose as each time there will be different number of values (4 or 8 or 12..).

The solution for this I see is to save it in an array, but I do not know how to save these values in array. Please tell me if I can do it. Tell me if there is any other method to get the result.

Comment: You shouldn't blindly use `/sgim` every time you write a regex: pick the ones you need to make your pattern work properly. And `/x` is probably the most important of all.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'FIELDS=(1,10,3,A,11,10,7,D,9,10,11,A)';

if ( $str =~ / FIELDS \s* = \s* \( ( [^)]* ) \) /x ) {
  my @fields = split /,/, $1;
  print "$_\n" for @fields;
}
```

**output**

```
1
10
3
A
11
10
7
D
9
10
11
A
```

Comment: Thanks @Borodin. Please split this `$str =~ / FIELDS \s* = \s* \( ( [^)]* ) \) /x`. Just want to understand its working!

Comment: And how is `print "$_\n" for @fields` working? This seems to be _for each value of @fields_. Is there any other way to write this? Sorry, I am new to perl.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to break you comma separated matches into individual pieces:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $line = 'FIELDS=(1,10,3,A,11,10,7,D,9,10,11,A)'

if ( my ($fields) = $line =~ /FIELDS=(\(.*\))/ ) {
   my @vars = split /,/, $fields; 
   # do whatever you want with @vars
}
```

Answer (score -1):

TIMTOWTDI. There is one of them:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    next unless /^FIELDS=\(([^)]*)\)/;
    my @fields = split ',', $1;
    while (@fields) {
        my @subfields = splice @fields, 0, 4;
        print "$. @subfields\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
FIELDS=(1,2,3,4)
FIELDS=(1,10,3,A,11,10,7,D,9,10,11,A)
```

Comment: Thanks @Hynek. Please tell me how `next unless /^FIELDS=\(([^)]*)\)/;` is working?

Comment: It skips lines which doesn't contain pattern. You can raise exception in this case as well `die "Wrong line '$_'" unless /^FIELDS=\(([^)]*)\)/;`. If pattern matches, it sets `$1` to the content inside parentheses and continues. `unless` works exactly same as `if not`.

Comment: @JustStarted: If you are confused with syntax see [perlsyn Statement Modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers). If you are confused by `next` keyword see [Loop Control](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Loop-Control).