# How to get values in different array from main array splitting by keyword in perl?

Tags: perl

I have one string `FORCE=(1,10,A,11,20,D,31,5,BI,A,36,9,NU,D,46,9,D)`
I want to store these values in different arrays when ever A/D is found, using perl.
Eg.

```
Array1=1,10,A

Array2=11,20,D

Array3=31,5,BI,A

Array4=36,9,NU,D

Array5=46,9,D
```

---

> It is not known that the bunch will be of 3 or 4 values!

---

Currently I am splitting the array with `split`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

@main = "FORCE=(1,10,A,11,20,D,31,5,BI,A,36,9,NU,D,46,9,D)";
my @val = split(/,/,$1);
print "Val Array = @val\n";
```

But how to proceed further?

Comment: This was already answered in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100071/getting-many-values-in-an-array-in-perl

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: No, it was not answered in this question. The previous question was about splitting by the constant number of elements. You should read more carefully.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: I don't see an answer to *this* question there?

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil Sure, now you need to determine how many elements to grab, the solution is almost the same. I would expect someone could extrapolate a solution with an added condition from the previous answers

Comment: Yep, _now you need to determine how many elements to grab_. It is very different task if you change problem from constant value to variable.

Comment: Clearly we don't agree, so it is probably not of benefit to discuss anymore. I marked as duplicate based on my previous argument.

Comment: Both the questions are different. [Pervious question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100071/getting-many-values-in-an-array-in-perl?lq=1) had a fixed pattern of 4 but this could have a pattern of 3 or 4 items, any one, any number of times!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Grab the stuff inside the parens.
my $input      = "FORCE=(1,10,A,11,20,D,31,5,BI,A,36,9,NU,D,46,9,D)";
my ($vals_str) = $input =~ /\(([^)]+)\)/;

# Get substrings of interest.
my @groups = $vals_str =~ /[^,].+?,[AD](?=,|$)/g;

# Split those into your desired arrays.
my @forces = map [split /,/, $_], @groups;
```

Note that this regex-based approach is reasonable for situations when you can assume that your input data is fairly clean. If you need to handle messier data and need your code to perform validation, I would suggest that you consider a different parsing strategy (as suggested in other answers).

Answer (score 1):

```
my $str = 'FORCE=(1,10,A,11,20,D,31,5,BI,A,36,9,NU,D,46,9,D)';

my ($list) = $str =~ /^[^=]*=\(([^()]*)\)$/
   or die("Unexpected format");

my @list = split(/,/, $list);

my @forces;
while (@list) {
   my @force;
   while (1) {
      die('No "A" or "D" value found') if !@list;
      push @force, shift(@list);
      last if $force[-1] eq 'A' || $force[-1] eq 'D';
   }

   push @forces, \@force;
}
```

Result:

```
@{$forces[0]} = (  1, 10, 'A' );
@{$forces[1]} = ( 11, 20, 'D' );
@{$forces[2]} = ( 31,  5, 'BI', 'A' );
@{$forces[3]} = ( 36,  9, 'NU', 'D' );
@{$forces[4]} = ( 46,  9, 'D' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils 'part';

# Grab the stuff inside the parens.
my $input = "FORCE=(1,10,A,11,20,D,31,5,BI,A,36,9,NU,D,46,9,D)";
my ($vals_str) = $input =~ /\(([^)]+)\)/;
my @val = split(/,/,$vals_str);
print "Val Array = @val\n";
my $i = 0;
my @partitions = part { $_ eq 'A' || $_ eq 'D' ? $i++ : $i } @val;
```

creates an array `@partitions` where each element is a reference to an array with the 3 or 4 elements you want grouped.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with some issues:

```
@main = "FORCE=(1,10,A,11,20,D,31,5,BI,A,36,9,NU,D,46,9,D)";
```

You have `use strict`, but first you never declare `@main`, and `@main` is an array, but you're assigning it a single string.

```
my @val = split(/,/,$1);
```

Where does `$1` come from?

```
print "Val Array = @val\n";
```

This might actually work. if `@val` had anything in it.

You have:

```
Array1=1,10,A
Array2=11,20,D
Array3=31,5,BI,A
Array4=36,9,NU,D
Array5=46,9,D
```

As your desired results. Are these scalar variables, or are these sub-arrays?

I'm going to assume the following:

- You need to convert your `FORCE` string into an array.
- You need your results in various arrays.

Because of this, I'm going to use an *Array of Arrays* which means I'm going to be using [References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

# Convert the string into an array
my $force = "FORCE=(1,10,A,11,20,D,31,5,BI,A,36,9,NU,D,46,9,D)";
$force =~ s/FORCE=\((.*)\)/$1/;    # Remove the "FORCE=(" prefix and the ")" suffix
my @main = split /,/, $force;      # Convert string into an array

my @array_of_arrays;               # Where I'm storing the arrays of arrays
my $array_of_arrays_number = 0;    # Array number I'm using for @arrays

while (@main)  {      # Going through my "@main" array one character at a time

    # Take a character from the @main array and put it onto whatever array of arrays you're pushing items into
    my $character = shift @main;
    push @{ $array_of_arrays[$array_of_arrays_number] }, $character;

    # If Character is 'A' or 'D', start a new array_of_arrays
    if ( $character eq 'A' or $character eq 'D' ) {
        $array_of_arrays_number += 1;
    }
}

# Let's print out these arrays
for my $array_number ( 0..$#array_of_arrays ) {
    say "Array$array_number = ", join ", ", @{ $array_of_arrays[$array_number] };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like functional approach so there is the version which makes splice indices first and then generates arrays of subarrays

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;

sub splice_force ($) {
    my $str = shift;
    croak "Unexpected format" unless $str =~ /^FORCE=\(([^()]*)\)/;
    my @list = split ',', $1;

    # find end positions for each splice
    my @ends = grep $list[$_] =~ /^[AD]$/, 0 .. $#list;

    # make array with starting positions
    my @starts = ( 0, map $_ + 1, @ends );

    #finally make splices (ignore last @starts element so iterate by @ends)
    map [ @list[ shift(@starts) .. $_ ] ], @ends;
}

my $str = 'FORCE=(1,10,A,11,20,D,31,5,BI,A,36,9,NU,D,46,9,D)';

print "@$_\n" for splice_force $str;
```

Comment: I can see a number of reasons why your solution may have been down-voted. *“Tested and working”* isn't a useful measure of the quality of your code

Comment: And reasons are? Sorry, I have to ask. If somebody care to downvote, he should care to explain.

Comment: No. There is no requirement to explain a vote on Stack Overflow, and you should get used to it as more often than not there is no explanation given

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without creating intermediate arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = q{FORCE=(1,10,A,11,20,D,31,5,BI,A,36,9,NU,D,46,9,D)};
my @groups = ([]);

while ($input =~ / ([A-Z0-9]+) ( [,)] ) /xg) {
    my ($token, $sep) = ($1, $2);
    push @{ $groups[-1] }, $token;
    $token =~ /\A(?:A|D)\z/
        or next;
    $sep eq ')'
        and last;
    push @groups, [];
}

use YAML::XS;
print Dump \@groups;
```

Output:

```
---     
- - '1' 
  - '10'
  - A   
- - '11'
  - '20'
  - D   
- - '31'
  - '5' 
  - BI  
  - A   
- - '36'
  - '9' 
  - NU  
  - D   
- - '46'
  - '9' 
  - D
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for anything more than [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). This solution checks that the string has the expected form and extracts the characters between the parentheses. Then that is split on commas that are preceded by a field that contains `A` or `D`, and the result is split again on commas.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;    # For \K regex pattern

my $str = 'FORCE=(1,10,A,11,20,D,31,5,BI,A,36,9,NU,D,46,9,D)';

my @parts;
if ( $str =~ /FORCE \s* = \s* \( ( [^)]+ ) \)/x ) {
  @parts = map [ split /,/ ], split / [AD] [^,]* \K , /x, $1;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@parts;
```

**output**

```
[
  [1, 10, "A"],
  [11, 20, "D"],
  [31, 5, "BI", "A"],
  [36, 9, "NU", "D"],
  [46, 9, "D"],
]
```